# Conveying "guinea pig"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, synonymes

Entre *cochon d'Inde* et *cobaye*, lequel sera plus facilement compris pour rendre *guinea pig* (c-à-d sujet volontaire ou non d’expériences) ?

Peut-on employer couramment *guinea pig* en français (avec ce sens) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*[Cobaye](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cobaye)* est le terme consacré pour désigner la personne utilisée pour une expérience. Je n'ai jamais entendu *cochon d'Inde* avec ce sens et encore moins *guinea pig* en français que ce soit au propre ou au figuré.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Cobaye est-il un mot répandu ?

Comment: @Dimitris Assez, oui, en particulier dans l'expression *servir de cobaye*.

Comment: Nickel, merci encore:-)!

Comment: "Cochon d'inde" est le terme usuel au Québec pour l'animal, mais pas au sens figuré.

Comment: @Circeus C'est pareil ici.

Comment: OH! Je me suis embrouillé, je croyais que "au sens propre ou figuré" faisait référence à cochon d'inde... Voilà ce qui arrive quand je répond avec pas assez de sommeil dans le corps.

Comment: @Circeus Donnez-vous du 'blé d'Inde' aux cochons d'Inde? ;)

Comment: @vc74 Je ne connais pas grand chose aux cochon d'indes (chez nous on a eu des chiens, des souris, des furets et un chinchilla), alors je ne saurais le dire :P